# Получить данные из БД на веб-страницу в SVG

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, json

Доброго времени суток.

Что требуется:

- забирать значения из MySQL и выводить их на веб-страницу.

Что есть:

- данные в MySQL

Что хотелось бы узнать у сообщества:

- Как реализовать механизм передачи? Что именно надо изучить? Ни фронтэндом, ни бэкэндом до этого не занимался.
- Как выглядит связка этого механизма передачи? Какие "технологии" или языки программирования использовать?

Предполагаемый механизм передачи:

- Веб-страница, посредство AJAX и JSON запрашивает необходимые данные у приложения на С#, которое, обрабатывая запрос, выполняет его у БД и отправляет ответ веб-странице. 
  Если метод реализации со стороны C# <-> MySQL мне понятен и уже приходилось реализовывать, то вот связку SVG+JS <-> C# - нет. 
  Воспользовавшись поиском остановился на связке SVG картинка, обрабатывается посредством JS, при помощи AJAX/JSON отправляет запросы серверу. 
  В свою очередь, на сервер поднят веб-сервис для приложения на C#?

В общем, осознаю что материал достаточно большой, времени достаточно. Но вот разложить по полочкам все незнакомые технологии - пока не получается. Везде мелькают всякие web socet'ы и ADO.NET и т.п. Покритикуйте схему, предложите свой, наиболее простой вариант. Если можно, то со ссылками на различные книги/курсы в интернете.

Т.е. Ещё раз, чтобы до конца донести мысль:
My SQL -> C# -> ??? ??? ??? -> веб-сервер со страничками где только SVG картинка + JS.

Comment: Стандарт SVG базируется на XML. c# хорошо работает с xml, и вы можете генерировать и отдавать xml (то есть svg) любого формата. Сгенерировать js тоже сложности не представляет.

Comment: Так же c# поддерживает и AJAX и JSON (net 4.0 напрямую, 2.0 через библиотеку) проблем строить даную схему не вижу. Пробуйте - получится.

Comment: Т.е. постепенные шаги разработки я наметил верно? Это радует.
Спасибо, в целом, на данный момент в процессе изучения AJAX и JSON и оформление запросов к C# - приложению.